# Flutter, How to get Observatory debugger URL programmatically?

Tags: flutter, dart

Are there any ways to programmatically get Observatory debugger URL like this

`http://127.0.0.1:49276/K-PoofiUguw=/`

inside the Flutter running application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researched, We can't get it on runtime.

But we can get it during launch the app using `vmservice-out-file` option.

Example:

```
flutter run -d deviceId --vmservice-out-file=[TEMP_FILE]
```

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/41583

**Update:** another ways is to use `flutter daemon` or `flutter attach`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the Dart VM URL like this:

```
ServiceProtocolInfo info = await Service.getInfo();
String url = info.serverUri.toString();
```